# Превратить строку в массив

Tags: массивы, jquery, javascript

Всё выводит правильно:

```
var arr = [[0, '- Не выбрано -'], [1, 'Значение 1']];
select._new('test', {width: 238}, arr);
```

```js
var select = {
  _new: function(id, obj, list) {
    var active_select = list[list.length - 1];
    template_list = '';

    if (active_select > -1) {
      var length_list = list.length - 1;
      var title_select = list[active_select][1];
      var value_select = active_select;
    } else {
      var length_list = list.length;
      var title_select = list[0][1];
      var value_select = 0;
    }

    for (i = 0; i < length_list; i++) {
      var key = list[i][0];
      var value = list[i][1];
      template_list += '\
    <a class="select_value_' + key + '" href="javascript://"><div>' + value + '</div></a>\
   ';
    }

    template_select = '\
   <div id="select_' + id + '" class="select" style="width: ' + obj.width + 'px;">\
    <div class="title">\
     <div class="select_title_wrap"><div class="select_title">' + title_select + '</div></div>\
     <div class="upnarrow"><div class="upnarrow_wrap"><div class="upnarrow_img"></div></div></div>\
    </div>\
    <div style="width: ' + obj.width + 'px" class="list">\
     <div class="navigate">' + template_list + ' <span class="navigate_append"></span></div>\
    </div>\
   </div>\
   <input value="' + value_select + '" type="hidden" id="select_value_' + id + '">\
   <input type="hidden" id="select_value_h_' + id + '">\
   \
  ';
    $('#' + id).html(template_select);

    $('#select_' + id).find('.title').click(function() {
      select._get(id, 'opened') ? select._closed(id) : select._show(id);
      value_id = select._get(id, 'value');
      value_id ? $('#select_' + id).find('.select_value_' + value_id + ' div').addClass('active') : $('#select_' + id).find('.select_value_0 div').addClass('active');
    });
    $('#select_' + id).find('.navigate a').click(function() {
      // получаем значение активированного пункта
      var value_select = $(this).attr('class').match(/([0-9]+)/);
      var value_select_result = value_select[1];
      // заносим значение в input
      $('#select_value_' + id).val(value_select_result);
      // присваиваем class активному пункту
      $('#select_' + id).find('.navigate a').find('div').removeClass('active');
      $(this).find('div').addClass('active');
      // назначаем title
      $('#select_' + id).find('.title .select_title').text($(this).text());
      // закрываем список
      select._closed(id);
    });
    // сбрасываем активность пунктов при наведении
    $('#select_' + id).find('.navigate a').hover(function() {
      $('#select_' + id).find('div').removeClass('active');
    });
    // проверка на использование
    $('#select_' + id).hover(function() {
      $('#select_value_h_' + id).val(1)
    }, function() {
      $('#select_value_h_' + id).val(0);
    });
    // закрываем, если не используется
    $('body').bind('click', function() {
      if ($('#select_value_h_' + id).val() == 0) {
        select._closed(id);
      }
    });
    // делаем активной правую часть со стрелкой
    $('#select_' + id).find('.title').hover(function() {
      var active_class = 'active';
      $(this).find('.upnarrow_wrap').addClass(active_class);
    }, function() {
      var active_class = 'active';
      $(this).find('.upnarrow_wrap').removeClass(active_class);
    });
  },
  _get: function(id, name) {
    switch (name) {
      case 'opened':
        return $('#select_' + id).attr('class').indexOf('show') > -1 ? 1 : 0;
      case 'value':
        return $('#select_value_' + id).val();
    }
  },
  _set_title: function(obj) {
    $('#select_value_' + obj.id).val(obj.value);
    $('#select_' + obj.id).find('.title .select_title').text(obj.title);
  },
  _show: function(id) {
    $('#select_' + id).addClass('show');
  },
  _closed: function(id) {
    $('#select_' + id).removeClass('show');
  }
}

$(function() {
  var arr = [
    [0, '- Не выбрано -'],
    [1, 'Значение 1']
  ];
  select._new('test', {
    width: 238
  }, arr);
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  background: #ffffff;
  font-family: tahoma, verdana, arial, sans-serif, Lucida Sans;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 11px;
  color: #444444;
  line-height: 1;
  margin: 10px;
}

.select {
  background: #ffffff;
}

.select .title {
  border: 1px solid #C0CAD5;
  overflow: hidden;
  line-height: 1;
  width: 100%;
  height: 20px;
  cursor: default;
}

.select .title .select_title_wrap {
  float: left;
}

.select .show {
  display: inline-block;
}

.select.show .title {
  display: block;
}

.select .title .select_title {
  padding: 4px 6px;
}

.select .title .upnarrow {
  float: right;
}

.select .title .upnarrow_wrap {
  background: #ffffff;
  border-left: 1px solid #ffffff;
  height: 20px;
  padding-top: 3px;
  padding-left: 5px;
  padding-right: 5px;
}

.select.show .upnarrow_wrap {
  background: #dae2ea !important;
  border-left: 1px solid #C0CAD5 !important;
}

.select .title .upnarrow_wrap.active {
  background: #dae2ea;
  border-left: 1px solid #C0CAD5;
}

.select .title .upnarrow_wrap:hover {
  background: #dae2ea;
  border-left: 1px solid #C0CAD5;
}

.select .title .upnarrow_wrap .upnarrow_img {
  display: inline-block;
  background: url('../images/darr_dd_out.gif') no-repeat;
  width: 7px;
  height: 4px;
}

.select.show .list {
  display: block !important;
}

.select .list {
  z-index: 2000;
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  background: #ffffff;
  border: 1px solid #C0CAD5;
  border-top: none !important;
}

.select .list .navigate {}

.select .list .navigate a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  outline: none;
  color: #444444;
}

.select .list .navigate div {
  line-height: 1;
  height: 13px;
  padding: 3px;
  padding-left: 10px !important;
}

.select .list .navigate div.active {
  background: #6083a5;
  border: 1px solid #346089;
  color: #ffffff !important;
  margin: -1px;
}

.select .list .navigate a:hover {
  background: #6083a5;
  border: 1px solid #346089 !important;
  color: #ffffff;
  margin: -1px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Сам вывод select в самом низу вкладки JavaScript --!>
<div id="test"></div>
```

Выводит неправильно, нужно как-то **текст превратить в массив**:

```
<div id="arr" style="display: none">[0, '- Не выбрано -'], [1, 'Значение 1']</div>

var arr = [$('#arr').text()];
select._new('test', {width: 238}, arr);
```

```js
var select = {
  _new: function(id, obj, list) {
    var active_select = list[list.length - 1];
    template_list = '';

    if (active_select > -1) {
      var length_list = list.length - 1;
      var title_select = list[active_select][1];
      var value_select = active_select;
    } else {
      var length_list = list.length;
      var title_select = list[0][1];
      var value_select = 0;
    }

    for (i = 0; i < length_list; i++) {
      var key = list[i][0];
      var value = list[i][1];
      template_list += '\
    <a class="select_value_' + key + '" href="javascript://"><div>' + value + '</div></a>\
   ';
    }

    template_select = '\
   <div id="select_' + id + '" class="select" style="width: ' + obj.width + 'px;">\
    <div class="title">\
     <div class="select_title_wrap"><div class="select_title">' + title_select + '</div></div>\
     <div class="upnarrow"><div class="upnarrow_wrap"><div class="upnarrow_img"></div></div></div>\
    </div>\
    <div style="width: ' + obj.width + 'px" class="list">\
     <div class="navigate">' + template_list + ' <span class="navigate_append"></span></div>\
    </div>\
   </div>\
   <input value="' + value_select + '" type="hidden" id="select_value_' + id + '">\
   <input type="hidden" id="select_value_h_' + id + '">\
   \
  ';
    $('#' + id).html(template_select);

    $('#select_' + id).find('.title').click(function() {
      select._get(id, 'opened') ? select._closed(id) : select._show(id);
      value_id = select._get(id, 'value');
      value_id ? $('#select_' + id).find('.select_value_' + value_id + ' div').addClass('active') : $('#select_' + id).find('.select_value_0 div').addClass('active');
    });
    $('#select_' + id).find('.navigate a').click(function() {
      // получаем значение активированного пункта
      var value_select = $(this).attr('class').match(/([0-9]+)/);
      var value_select_result = value_select[1];
      // заносим значение в input
      $('#select_value_' + id).val(value_select_result);
      // присваиваем class активному пункту
      $('#select_' + id).find('.navigate a').find('div').removeClass('active');
      $(this).find('div').addClass('active');
      // назначаем title
      $('#select_' + id).find('.title .select_title').text($(this).text());
      // закрываем список
      select._closed(id);
    });
    // сбрасываем активность пунктов при наведении
    $('#select_' + id).find('.navigate a').hover(function() {
      $('#select_' + id).find('div').removeClass('active');
    });
    // проверка на использование
    $('#select_' + id).hover(function() {
      $('#select_value_h_' + id).val(1)
    }, function() {
      $('#select_value_h_' + id).val(0);
    });
    // закрываем, если не используется
    $('body').bind('click', function() {
      if ($('#select_value_h_' + id).val() == 0) {
        select._closed(id);
      }
    });
    // делаем активной правую часть со стрелкой
    $('#select_' + id).find('.title').hover(function() {
      var active_class = 'active';
      $(this).find('.upnarrow_wrap').addClass(active_class);
    }, function() {
      var active_class = 'active';
      $(this).find('.upnarrow_wrap').removeClass(active_class);
    });
  },
  _get: function(id, name) {
    switch (name) {
      case 'opened':
        return $('#select_' + id).attr('class').indexOf('show') > -1 ? 1 : 0;
      case 'value':
        return $('#select_value_' + id).val();
    }
  },
  _set_title: function(obj) {
    $('#select_value_' + obj.id).val(obj.value);
    $('#select_' + obj.id).find('.title .select_title').text(obj.title);
  },
  _show: function(id) {
    $('#select_' + id).addClass('show');
  },
  _closed: function(id) {
    $('#select_' + id).removeClass('show');
  }
}

$(function() {
  var arr = [$('#arr').text()];
  select._new('test', {
    width: 238
  }, arr);
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  background: #ffffff;
  font-family: tahoma, verdana, arial, sans-serif, Lucida Sans;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 11px;
  color: #444444;
  line-height: 1;
  margin: 10px;
}

.select {
  background: #ffffff;
}

.select .title {
  border: 1px solid #C0CAD5;
  overflow: hidden;
  line-height: 1;
  width: 100%;
  height: 20px;
  cursor: default;
}

.select .title .select_title_wrap {
  float: left;
}

.select .show {
  display: inline-block;
}

.select.show .title {
  display: block;
}

.select .title .select_title {
  padding: 4px 6px;
}

.select .title .upnarrow {
  float: right;
}

.select .title .upnarrow_wrap {
  background: #ffffff;
  border-left: 1px solid #ffffff;
  height: 20px;
  padding-top: 3px;
  padding-left: 5px;
  padding-right: 5px;
}

.select.show .upnarrow_wrap {
  background: #dae2ea !important;
  border-left: 1px solid #C0CAD5 !important;
}

.select .title .upnarrow_wrap.active {
  background: #dae2ea;
  border-left: 1px solid #C0CAD5;
}

.select .title .upnarrow_wrap:hover {
  background: #dae2ea;
  border-left: 1px solid #C0CAD5;
}

.select .title .upnarrow_wrap .upnarrow_img {
  display: inline-block;
  background: url('../images/darr_dd_out.gif') no-repeat;
  width: 7px;
  height: 4px;
}

.select.show .list {
  display: block !important;
}

.select .list {
  z-index: 2000;
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  background: #ffffff;
  border: 1px solid #C0CAD5;
  border-top: none !important;
}

.select .list .navigate {}

.select .list .navigate a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  outline: none;
  color: #444444;
}

.select .list .navigate div {
  line-height: 1;
  height: 13px;
  padding: 3px;
  padding-left: 10px !important;
}

.select .list .navigate div.active {
  background: #6083a5;
  border: 1px solid #346089;
  color: #ffffff !important;
  margin: -1px;
}

.select .list .navigate a:hover {
  background: #6083a5;
  border: 1px solid #346089 !important;
  color: #ffffff;
  margin: -1px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Сам вывод select в самом низу вкладки JavaScript --!>
<div id="arr" style="display: none">[0, '- Не выбрано -'], [1, 'Значение 1]</div>
<div id="test"></div>
```

Нужно кликнуть на сам прямоугольник и там должен быть список. Ссылки на jsfiddle приложены для сравнения.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Приведите к валидному формату JSON:

```
<div id="arr" style="display: none">[["0", "- Не выбрано -"], ["1", "Значение 1"]]</div>
```

И тогда:

```
var arr = JSON.parse($('#arr').text());
```

ЗЫ [json2.min.js](http://yandex.st/json2/2011-10-19/json2.min.js)

Comment: @Yura Ivanov, знаете что я Вам скажу, Вы гений! Неоднократно спасаете своими ответами. Только вместо библиотеки с парсингом json, в jquery есть $.parseJSON(text);. Спасибо огромное!

Comment: json2 быстрее. jquery.parseJSON пытается использовать нативный парсер браузера и если он недоступен, то используется аналог eval. [обсуждение на SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10362277/jquery-parsejson-vs-json-parse)